# Mass of the kaon (1460)

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, mesons

When looking at the particle listing in [PDG](https://pdg.lbl.gov/) most of the hadron masses and excitation include an experimental error. But this is not the case for the Kaon (1460), does anybody know why? This means the mass is inconclusive or something?

Here is the link of the kaon(1460)
https://pdg.lbl.gov/2022/listings/rpp2022-list-K-1460.pdf